# Can a client trust a certificate from a CA on its same level? (or further down)

Tags: certificate-authority

On a PKI where all clients get their certs from the 2nd level issuing certificate authority, if a new CA pops up with a legitimate certificate from the chain but deeper in the hierarchy, will clients on the same level of the CA trust the children of it? These would be certificates with an additional ***unknown CA*** (the third) but with the familiar certificates from the root and subordinate CA (2nd level) in the chain?

I know there's something like cross-domain CAs or something like that, but this technically would be the same domain, different subdomain, if at all. Valid or not, there's no reason why a 3rd or 10th level CA wouldn't issue certificate for the top level, is there??

I did a little sketch explain it better:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Does that comes from a real case you observed or is just an hypothetical question? Because I would seriously doubt any CA to do something like that (using same certificate to sign end client certificates and also other subCAs). Also look at the `pathLenConstraint` proprety of a certificate, and the "name constraints" extension.

Answer (score 2):

A client can trust a deeper certificate, but it entirely automatic.

With most TLS servers you have a way to provide a bundle of intermediate certificates in addition to the certificate used for that endpoint.

So the Letsencrypt root is trusted by most browsers/clients

- https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem.txt

But the certificates from Letsencrypt come from a deeper CA that isn't typically trusted directly.  The server must include the intermediate.

- https://letsencrypt.org/certs/letsencryptauthorityx3.pem.txt

So when the client gets connects it will get the intermediates, and the certificate for the resource it is connecting too.  It will attempt to trust chain from the root, through the intermediates down to the cert.

So lets look at the case of https://serverfault.com/.  My system only trusts the top 'DigiCert' CA, it does not trust 'DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA'.  But I can use https://serverfault.com/ because the server returns the intermediates.

[image: stackexchange cert]

If you want to fire up the CLI you can see the certs with openssl

```
echo '' | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect serverfault.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = NY, L = New York, O = "Stack Exchange, Inc.", CN = *.stackexchange.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/C=US/ST=NY/L=New York/O=Stack Exchange, Inc./CN=*.stackexchange.com
  i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIIP... # the intermediate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
  i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEs... # cert for stackexchange
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/C=US/ST=NY/L=New York/O=Stack Exchange, Inc./CN=*.stackexchange.com
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3945 bytes and written 269 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
...
```

So a client doesn't automatically trust deeper CAs, but it is easy to configure things so certs can be trusted.